# Merging two joined tables and output as JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, pg

I want to `SELECT` entities and an `uploads` JSON array column containing all of their uploads, along with the `cover` and `profile` fields for each upload.

So far, I can get the array of uploads, but I am unable to add the two other fields from the `entitiesXuploads` table.

A basic representation of my **three tables** is as such:

`Entities`

- id (int8)
- name (varchar)

`Uploads`

- id (uuid)
- title (varchar)
- versions (jsonb)

`entitiesXuploads`

- entityId (int8)
- uploadId (uuid)
- cover (bool)
- profile (bool)

My query:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.name,
    COALESCE(jsonb_agg(up) FILTER (WHERE up."id" IS NOT NULL), '[]') as uploads

FROM 
    entities as e
    LEFT JOIN "entitiesXuploads" as exu ON exu."entityId" = e."id"
    LEFT JOIN "uploads" as up ON up."id" = exu."uploadId"

GROUP BY
    e.id,
    e.name
```

Which returns rows with:

- id (entity id)
- name (entity name)
- uploads (json array of uploads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3cf4b8a63a172125c6e2d5d8afb7be29)

```
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.name,
    jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'upload_id', upload_id, 
            'title', title, 
            'versions', versions,
            'cover', cover,
            'profile', profile
        )
    ) AS uploads
FROM
    entities e
JOIN entities_uploads eu ON e.id = eu.entity_id
JOIN uploads u ON eu.upload_id = u.id
GROUP BY e.id, e.name
```

You can use `jsonb_build_object()` to create the object you are expecting for each record. After that you can group the records using the `jsonb_agg()` aggregate function to merge these objects into one array.

Comment: Perfect, I added my COALESCE around your working `jsonb_agg` function to have empty `[]` when no id is found. Works great!

Comment: If there is no id, the JOIN will not add the record. So there is no reason for that. If you really need a LEFT JOIN as in your example then it you'll need something like that.

Comment: had to keep the LEFT and also just realized at times it was giving me duplicate items in the `uploads` array so I added `DISTINCT` in front of the `jsonb_build_object` function and all is well now :)